# Can I use a plain View as a widget?

Tags: android, view, widget, android-widget

so as the question explains I want to know if I can use a standard view in my widget, I'm aware that widgets only allow certain types of views, namely they are :  AnalogClock Button Chronometer ImageButton ImageView ProgressBar TextView ViewFlipper ListView GridView StackView AdapterViewFlipper, the documentation also says "Descendants of these classes are not supported." but what about the parent? can I use a normal view in my widget layout nothing fancy or custom just a plain view? say like this

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
        android:id="@+id/unread_count_badge"/>
```

Comment: How would it differ from using an ImageView?

Comment: as far as I'm aware it wouldn't would it? for instance 
ImageView
public class ImageView 
extends View

Comment: I'm fully open to the answer to this being a simple yes or no

Comment: Or "I have no clue". I trust you when you say it's not mentioned. So what I can tell you is: TRY and see. If it doesn't work, then use an ImageView and be happy with that.

Comment: lol yeah i guess so, image views are better anyway who cares lol

Comment: Well, not really. Views are simpler and less specialized. Therefore the use of a View could help you gain some nanosecond - if you care. But, probably, the gain is  actually NEGLIGIBLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. You can only use widgets that describes in official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

Comment: yup thats right Binary XML file line #87: Class not allowed to be inflated android.view.View